# Is there a way to get custom fields for customers through the API?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

The bigcommerce UI allows users to make custom fields (or "form fields") for customers; but the api documentation doesn't show any way to retrieve these fields or the data contained in them. Hopefully a hidden, undocumented feature?